# Apply divide formula to entire row in macro on Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, divide

I am tring to fix a problem.

Like Copy / Special Pasta - divide, i would like to do it in VBA.

For example, I have numbers from A to AA.

I want to divide the range A5:AA5 by 2 completely.
It’s like a special paste, divide the values.

It will continue like this until it reaches an empty cell in A6:AA6 / 2, A7:AA7 / 2, and so on.

But i dont want to make each cells divide or Sum of divide, like selecting all C2:H2 and divide by 2.

Anyone can help?

[image]

Comment: You understand correctly, i guess there is no way to make all range in one shot divide.

Comment: You can however divide the range very easily but it'll involve going into some sort of loop/iteration. Why exactly is that an issue for you? Dividing a range could take less than a second if you do it right so I don't see a need for a "one-shot".

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it is using the PasteSpecial command.  The trick is to put the number you want to divide by in a cell, copy it, .PasteSpecial, and then remove the data from that cell. Something like this:

```
Range("C9").Value = 2    
Range("C9").Copy
Range("A5:F5").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlDivide
Range("C9").ClearContents
```

Obviously there are various ways to add data to a cell, delete data, etc.  But I wanted to give you a quick example that you can modify to fit your sheet's layout.

If you want to use a loop, here is a way:

```
Sub test2()
Dim x As Long

Dim rng As Range
Dim c As Range

x = 2

Set rng = Range("A5:F5")

For Each c In rng
    c.Value = c.Value / x
Next c

End Sub
```

Someone smarter than me will have to chime in w/ @BigBen's suggestion of using an array.

Comment: Ok, I stand corrected, apparently there is a functionality like it. Thanks for the insight, I'll delete my comment below OP's question.

Comment: Yeah, it's not the most intuitive thing but glad I could help and good luck with the rest of your project!

Comment: I'm not OP but thanks for letting me learn regardless ;)

Comment: thank you for answer, it seems only solution is doing by paste special. I will try to do it in a loop.

Comment: You can do this using an array if you don't want to use Copy/PasteSpecial

Comment: @BigBen if possible can you give example?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example using an array:

```
Dim arr() As Variant
arr = Range("A5:AA5").Value

Dim i As Long, j As Long
For i = LBound(arr, 1) To Ubound(arr, 1)
    For j = Lbound(arr, 2) To Ubound(arr, 2)
        arr(i, j) = arr(i, j) / 2
    Next
Next

Range("A5:AA5").Value = arr
```